# How to delete ghost node that was created by accidental renaming and changing back of actual node

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am in a bit of a messy situation here.

My network broke a few days back and logstash agent gave exceptions. 
I was relatively new at this and not as well read as now. I restarted the elasticsearch service and logstash process a couple times but it didnt work. In my frenzy i renamed the single node that i have on my cluster as it was giving me a "**NoNodeAvailable" Exception**. I found that it didn't help and again changed it back to previous name. 
Now i have **2 nodes** in my **data dir 0 & 1**.

`"cluster_name" : "logging_gsds",
 "status" : "red",
"timed_out" : false,
"number_of_nodes" : 1,
"number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
"active_primary_shards" : 472,
"active_shards" : 472,
"relocating_shards" : 0,
"initializing_shards" : 4,
**"unassigned_shards" : 534**`

This shows in my cluster health.

How do i check/delete this new node as i don't have a name or ip assigned for it??

This is what i get when i run logstash-

`org.elasticsearch.index.mapper: Type [postgresql_9.2_log] contains a '.', it is recommended not to include it within a type name`

Repeats itself with different dated indices!

Also, my elasticsearch.yml is configured to default. Meaning no. of shards 5 and no. of replicas 1. However before this incident there was only one configured node. 
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by completely dumping this node and creating another one. The issue with this node was that while it was the only one in the cluster the replica was set to 1. Since there wasn't any other node available in the cluster to replicate on, there were a lot of unassigned shards. This had resulted in the health being red. I think this crashed the cluster because there wasn't any other explanation really.